# Source control and IntelliJ Idea Android project

Tags: java, android, version-control, intellij-idea

I am new to the Java world, having spent the past decade working in the cozy Microsoft world. My first project is Android app, utilising Google Maps v2 for Android, amongst other things. I had a look at the FAQ for IntelliJ idea and followed their recommendation on what to add in the `.gitignore` file. Basically I have:

```
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
out/
```

However, when I cloned the same repository on another machine I lost all my Module Settings. I'm still very fuzzy about these Modules and Library settings for the project and couldn't help thinking in terms of VS.NET references. Have I missed something in my commit?

Comment: I mean ... you explicitly excluded your IDE settings files so yes, they're excluded. If that's not what you want, don't do that. Projects with more than one developer often do this to avoid conflicts between settings.

Comment: I assume `workspace.xml` is where these settings are? Can we reduce such conflicts if we have the SDK and other referenced libraries in identical paths?

Comment: Honestly, I don't use IntelliJ so I'm afraid I have no idea what is in those .xml files. Take a peek, they're just XML.